# Uncaught ReferenceError: handleLocationError is not defined google maps api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, http, header

I have this problem

`getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.`

I therefore throws this error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: handleLocationError is not defined`

So I call the api

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ADVJFGFNFV4B2wTtyywqsMs--NTpg2w0&libraries=drawing,places"></script>`

Production gives me error

[image]

Local works perfectly

[image]

One solution is to use https.
**But there is another alternative?**

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has deprecated this in version 50. There is no plan to allow it in HTTP.

> localhost is treated as a secure origin over HTTP, so if you're able to run your server from localhost, you should be able to test the feature on that server.

That's why it works on local. Now, your only way is to use HTTPS, maybe you could use a service like https://letsencrypt.org/ (It’s free, automated, and open.)

Good luck.